# Using custom <oembed> tags with HTMLPurifier

Tags: html, security, htmlpurifier

I want to use and tags as well as some custom tags (`<oembed>`) with HTMLPurifier. I used

$config->set('HTML.Allowed','oembed');
to add those tags but it didn't work

I also try this

$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'data-id', 'Number');

```
$def->addElement( 'oembed',  //name
                             'Inline', //content set
                             'Inline', //allowed children
                             'I18N', //attribute collection
                             array( 'src*' => 'URI',
                                    'height*' => 'Pixels',
                                    'width*' => 'Pixels')
                           );
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I think it’s not as simple as that ... you need to make your custom element know to the parser first ... http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html

Comment: @CBroe I edit the question